# Coloring the area under graph

Tags: css, d3.js

I am stuck and thought to get your help to move on forward.

I am trying to shade the area under my line chart with different colors. I know there is the concept of gradient but I want to color it based on my data.
For example and value below zero is red , between 1 and 5 is pink and above 5 is black. Is there a way to this ?

this is the snippet for my shaded area

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function (d) { return x(d.timex); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function (d) { return y(d.conct); });

 svg.append("path")
       .datum(data)
       .attr("class", "area")
       .attr("d", area);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a **clip path**, one for each different color you want to show with your area. In theory, the clip path will be multiple rectangle indicating where you want the area object to show through. You'll need one clip path and area for each color.

In practice, I found Mike Bostock use a clip path (briefly) with D3 [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/), and MDN has a reasonably good reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking). You can go from there to google around for more examples; just make sure they're talking about SVG clip paths.

Comment: I also found this link useful for understanding clip paths: http://apike.ca/prog_svg_clip.html

Comment: @mgold : Thanks for the help. I tried using gradient and was able to color the area. Is there a way where the offset value for the gradient can be actually the values of an array ?

Comment: I didn't suggest using a gradient. If you want 5 different colors, use 5 different areas, each with solid fill, and use clip paths.